# Ordering of relation based on associated table in rails4

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have 2 models as below:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :marks
end

class Mark < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :student
end
```

`point` is a field in marks table. For each student there are many entries in the marks table.

I need to get a list of students based on the order of highest total points.

I tried as below:

```
@students = Student.all.collect{|p| [p,p.marks.pluck(:point).sum]}
@students.sort_by { |h| h[1] }.reverse!
```

But it will return 2 items in each array, one the object and next the total points.

Is there a better solution please.

Thanks,

Jissy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Student.joins(:marks).select('students.*, SUM(marks.point) AS total_point').group(:id).order('total_point DESC')
```

Comment: A small change gave me the result:Student.joins(:marks).select('students.*, SUM(marks.point) AS total_point').group('students.id').order('total_point DESC')    .                        Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this.

```
 Student.joins(:marks).select('id, sum(marks.point) as total_marks').group('students.id').order('total_marks desc')
```

If you are still unable to run it please modify it or let me know.In place of id in select you can select any column(s).